# Laravel exception handling: exception with "wrong" class

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I use a single Closure to handle exceptions in my app:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if (is_a($exception, 'MsgException')) {
        ...
        return;
    }
    dd($exception); // debugging
});
```

The strange thing is that if I throw a `MsgException`...

```
<?php use MsgException; // alias for ExampleNamespace\MsgException

...
throw new MsgException();
```

...which is a custom class...

```
<?php namespace ExampleNamespace;

use RuntimeException;

class MsgException extends RuntimeException {}
```

... `is_a($exception)` is `false` and `dd($exception)` says it's an `ErrorException`.

I have no idea why this is happening. Any suggestions or ideas how I can debug my application?

Comment: why don't u just catch the exception and see where it really originates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the short answer is pretty simple: It's not working because the exception is thrown inside of a view. 
You can test this by simple adding

```
throw new \RuntimeException('Test');
```

to a controller method or a routing closure or any place outside a view and by adding

```
<?php throw new \RuntimeException('Test'); ?>
```

to a view template. Laravel will show the first one as a `RuntimeException` and the second as an `ErrorException`.

Unfortunately this isn't helping to actually solve the problem.

PS: In Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine the handleViewException method replaces the original exception:

```
protected function handleViewException($e, $obLevel)
{
    $e = new \ErrorException($this->getMessage($e), 0, 1, $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e);

    parent::handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the general Exception handler to handle other types of exceptions. Register your own.

```
App::error(function(ExampleNamespace\MsgException $exception, $code)
{
    dd($exception); // debugging
});
```

More read about `App::error` are available [here](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors).

Comment: Tanks, but that's not addressing the problem (however I tried it this way but it's not working - ofcourse not)